# Number of light neutrinos from the Z lineshape: an unexpected detail

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics

It is well known that the number of light neutrino species can be deduced from the measurement of the visible partial widths of the Z, and the total width of the Z, by comparing the difference to the theoretical prediction for partial width of a single neutrino:

$$\Gamma^Z_{total} = \Gamma^Z_{visible} + \Gamma^Z_{invisible} = \sum_f \Gamma^Z_{f\bar{f}} + N*\Gamma^Z_{\nu},$$

where N is the number of light neutrino species, $\Gamma^Z_{total}$ can be determined from the Z lineshape, $\Gamma^Z_{f\bar{f}}$ can be measured from partial widths to fermions pairs, and $\Gamma^Z_{\nu}$ can be computed.

What I do not understand is the plots showing the Z lineshape in case of different numbers of neutrino species, such as [this one](http://www.fnal.gov/pub/today/images/images11/CMSResult031111_supplementalfigure1.jpg).

My question is: why is the lineshape with larger number of neutrino species the narrowest one? Even though the partial width to quarks is shown, the lineshape should be wider as far as I know (the total width is the property of the particle, regardless of what it decays to).

Comment: The 4$\nu$ lineshape in the plot you link is the widest one. Annoyingly they aren't normalised to the same area, so it's difficult to compare.

Comment: This paper (https://arxiv.org/pdf/hep-ex/0509008.pdf) doesn't mention anything about what you are suggesting.

Answer (score 0):

The comment by dukwon is correct, I've made a python notebook to convince myself:

https://github.com/mzgubic/Z-width/blob/master/Z-width.ipynb

Basically the larger width makes the peak lower. The different width should really be compared at the FWHM of the shape, which is difficult to do visually.

Answer (score -1):

[This talk](https://www.nikhef.nl/~h84/APP-lecture5.pdf) shows two ways of determining the number of neutrinow with the Z width.

The two ways of determining the number of neutrinos depend in determining a crossection  where the neutrino component contributes by default:

In the hadronic crossection width,which is the plot you link, where the neutrino contributions are not detected and thus are seen as a missing crossection. So one defines the visible width . (page 17)

[image: visiblewidth]

Calculate it in the standard model with two three or four neutrino species. The more neutrino species the less is the peak crossection as the extra neutrinos take away a part of the width.

The same is true for the second collider method, on page 18.

Comment: Sorry, but this is incorrect. Sure, the visible width is not affected by the number of neutrino species, but the width of the particle is the total width, which is the sum of the visible and invisible width, and is seen as the FWHM of the resonance in any decay channel.

Furthermore, the peak xsection is reduced by the width on the bottom of the propagator, not because 'the width is taken away'. To the best of my knowledge the visible width is also independent of the number of neutrino species, and is determined by the product of gw, mZ, and vector and axial constants.

Comment: We cannot measure the total width as the neutrinos are invisible and in the collider there is no way to detect that the reaction has happened.( It is not the elastic crossection that is calculated)

Comment: Indeed you can measure the total width - it is the total FWHM of the resonance.

Comment: only in the elastic crossection. The plots and calculations are from the interaction products.

Comment: Sorry, could you elaborate on the last comment?

Comment: I went for a walk. Did you look at the lecture in the link ? The plot where the different neutrino calculations are plotted are total Z0 to anything crossection. this includes the neutrino channels which cannot be measured in the lab thus the visible width use.

Comment: Okay, let me try one last time: partial widths are measureable from cross sections, and indeed in this way we can only determine the visible width. However, the shape of the resonance contains information on the total width - hence, if we can measure a single decay channel with sufficient resolution, we are able to deduce the total width. I suspect you think that the Z resonance to muons has the lineshape width equal to the partial width to muons - this is incorrect.

Comment: did you look at the formulae? Yes that is what is a basic assumption,. look at page 5 here www-pnp.physics.ox.ac.uk/~barra/teaching/resonances.pdf . The shape shown is not the remainder of subtracting a single resonace but of all the neutrino channels  ( if you mean the squat versus the tall) . It is not the individual shape of a resonance itself, except if it had 1 neutrino species

Comment: OK, I think our disagreement is based on this assertion of yours : " the shape of the resonance contains information on the total width - hence, if we can measure a single decay channel with sufficient resolution, we are able to deduce the total width."  Do you have a link for this ?

Comment: This is undergrad physics really: the width of the particle is a physical property of the particle, inversely related to the lifetime. Indeed, it is also contained in the formula you provide above, the width of the resonance (mathematically) arises from the second term in the denominator, which has total width in it, not the partial width to the final state.

Comment: When I measure the width of the Z  in e+e- ->e+e-  elastic  scattering yes, I get the total width through the optical theorem . But for the decay to individual channels I do not see how this could be true.  That is why I want a link to your claim.

Comment: Is it using the SU(3)xSU(2)xU(1) symmetry of the standard model? But the standard model is for 3 neutrino species. The hypothesis of less or more will change the calculations which is what the plot shows, imo.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relativistic_Breit-Wigner_distribution